# how to deploy a simple node application on server

Tags: node.js

I have written a simple node app that reads a list of contact from mysql database and send an email using Sendgrid api.

It works in Visual Studio Code, but ho am I supposed to port it on my hosting? It is a regular Linux based hosting plan.

What are the steps that I should follow? I can only find how to build node application that run on express server, but I have no server in my app.

Here is the content of the index.js file:

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

var mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'user',
  password: 'password',
  database: 'schema'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * FROM test_mailsend', function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;

  results.forEach(function (e) {
    const msg = {
      to: [e.email], // replace these with your email addresses
      from: 'Test Test <hello@test@it>',
      subject: ' Donuts, at the big donut ',
      text: 'Fresh donuts are out of the oven. Get them while they’re hot!',
      html: '<p>Fresh donuts are out of the oven. Get them while they’re <em>hot!</em></p>',
    };

    sgMail.sendMultiple(msg).then(() => {
      console.log('emails sent successfully!');
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

  });

});

connection.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright, so first of all you can use git, and commit the code to online repository. Once you have, you should open SSH connection to your linux server, and clone the code there. Then you need to install node on the server. Then you can run

```
 node index.js
```

But that will work only once, every time you run the command. If you for example want to send emails everytime an event is envoked, you should build server application (using Node, or I recommend using Express) and create REST api.

Here are some learning resources

1. Since I don't know what hosting provider you are using, I can't really provide anything.
2. [Express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)
3. [Rest API](https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/api/what-is-a-rest-api)

Comment: oh, I see... I think I cannot manage my hosting via SSH. Anyway, thanks for you answer. I'll try my best to understand how to go on with this